# Attack Range for adc champions?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there a way in **League of Legends** to view a marksman's attack range? There was an option to have it appear in the status window roughly a year ago but I'm now getting back into the swing of playing and would like to know the new ranges for the characters I play.

Does anyone know where I can view this stat?

Comment: I think there is a number with the range in the hidden stats, but i think when you ask where you can view that stat, its just an UI range, right?

Comment: I don't know but I imagine there should be a way to check it when your in a match. For example Tristana gains more range per level the last I checked by I can't see this range or the scale at which it increases. Another example is Caitlyn in alot of forums I read that she has huge range as an ADC but I don't actually see this range. When I play I just imagine a big bubble around my champ and aim at whatever is closest to it.

Comment: You can see in-game visually the area you can cover with your AA by pressing A

Comment: Really? I'll try it when I get home.

Comment: @JustDoIt That does not work for mine. Is there a setting or something for it to turn on and off?

Comment: im not sure, ill check when i get home

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a little over a year ago the User Interface was changed, and stats regarding your character were moved. They were moved from that big ol' box into a really slim box.

To access this new slim box, you can click on the circle at the left-down corner of the screen (It has what appears to be a small helmet). That button toggles the character information box and shows some of your character stats, however it doesn't show all of them.

To open the box mentioned above, and one other box, you can click on C, which will then open both boxes, and it contains all stats pertinent to that champion, including movement speed and auto attack range

Comment: Note that it only shows the range in gameunits, it's currently (I hope it will be implemented someday) not possible to show the actual area where you can auto attack (like you can do with spells)

Comment: After playing I game I checked the box you mentioned but the only things in it are Attack damage, ability power, magic resistance, armor, movement speed , cool down reduction and attack speed not range.

Comment: @Hikari That's the regular box, you can expand it by pressing (and holding) C. That way you reveal Attack Range, Armor/Magic Penetrations and a few other stats

Comment: Can confirm the box that appears while holding C shows range. It's the bottom left value of the top box. If you want a visual you can hover over that value, or you can use A and X for attack move.

Comment: Can also confirm just played a game and tried it. You can see your own only. Wish they allowed you to see another champ.Kind of hard to see who you have reach on. If it's like MF vs Jinx and stuff like that. Upvotes for all who helped.

Comment: Yes, that's not possible. You can only view the "basic stats" by left clicking on the enemy champion, which brings a box to your left top corner. But hey, at least you can view their buffs/debuffs ;)

Answer (score 1):

Outside of game for evaluation/planning purposes, if you go to http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Champion and mouseover the champion name in the Champions list it tells range.  It also says it if you click into each champion.

Obviously it's a wiki, so it's info is as good as the updater, but I think it provides what you're looking for.

Comment: This seems like the only viable option. Wish there was a way for me to see it in game/ Oh well.. Dare to dream I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the number of units you can attack, hold C and a pop-up will show you the number of units your character can auto attack, normal numbers include 650 for Caitlyn, 550 for Lucian, and it varies from champion to champion.

If you're trying to get a visual representation while you're in a game click the a key. Your cursor will become a diamond with a dot in the middle like when you use spells (if you don't quick cast) and a circle will appear around your champion showing you your auto attack range in a very visual sense.

Comment: Caitlyn!!!!! I love range. Sgt. Hammer!!!!!! Xerath!!!!!